# Angular 7 Reactive Forms Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I am using `ReactiveForms` in Angular v7.

**Template**

```html
<div class="login__container">
    <div class="login__form">
        <form novalidate [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <button class="button is-success" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login-component',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm: FormGroup
    submitted = false

    constructor(private fB: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginForm = this.fB.group({
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        })
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() {
        return this.loginForm.controls
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return
        }

        console.log(this.loginForm.value)
    }
}
```

When I go to this route, I have a console error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
    at Object.get [as f] (http://localhost:4200/main.js:257:35)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92667:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92664:33)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92670:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92664:33)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92670:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepFreeze (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:92664:33)
```

I cannot work out why this happening, the validation around the submit button appears to be working, so I can only assume the fields are being referenced correctly. I suspect the issue is coming from the convenience getter set within the component, however I cannot see what is wrong with this as autocomplete is providing me with the values I expect.

Comment: check first 'this.loginForm' is undefined or not in f method. or else you can use loginForm.controls.username.errors in the HTML.

Comment: Another option is to pass the `formBuilder` from `ngOnInit` cycle to `constructor` cycle

Comment: As it is, Im not able to reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpstaz

Comment: As @OmerShukar mentioned, you could try by instantiating the form in the `constructor`

Comment: Using the constructor did not help, it also doesn’t appear to follow the docs set out by Angular.

Comment: In Case: If you did not find the any issue with form then may be angular application has some error in other part of code. Check carefully what you have changed recently. In my case, I was implementing encryption/decrption for localstorage and I was using wrong bits of key and iv.

Comment: I fixed it. I moved to React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the convenience method you are using, you could simply reference the field like

```
[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && loginForm.controls['username'].errors }"
```

It would then be a case of showing an error message if you so wish using

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && loginForm.controls['username'].hasError('required')" class="error-message">Username is required</div>
```

I am not clear on what benefit your current approach is affording you over something straight forward such as this.

Comment: This wont make a difference

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty easy to fix by checking `loginForm` in html.

```
<div class="login__container" *ngIf="loginForm"> <!-- Check here -->
    <div class="login__form">
        <form novalidate [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <p class="control">
                    <button class="button is-success" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```